# codeigniter Jquery Sortable list save in database

Tags: codeigniter, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to save these lists after reordering the lists and reloading the page. I can move the list through srtable jquery but I can't save these to the database in codeigniter. Below is the code for the View part.

**View:**

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      revert: true
    });
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
      connectToSortable: "#sortable",
      helper: "clone",
      revert: "invalid"
    });
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
  });
```

```css
 ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; }
  li { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 150px; }
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable + Sortable</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`update`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) option to add a callback that then calls whatever ajax you need to update the database.

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      revert: true,
      update: function( event, ui ) {
        alert('make your call to whatever controller via ajax here')
      }
    });
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
      connectToSortable: "#sortable",
      helper: "clone",
      revert: "invalid"
    });
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
  });
```

```css
ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; }
  li { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 150px; }
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable + Sortable</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

 
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @silent.tracker That's alright.  Everyone starts somewhere and it sounds like you're trying.  Which part are you stuck at?  I assume you have data in the database.  does the database have a sort order column or similar?  We'll probably end up needing to move over to chat.stackoverflow.com if the comments get too long.

Comment: @silent.tracker That complicates things... So you are stuck at the controller and model part.  You'll also need a second column.  ID should be separate from your sort order.  You should create a method in your controller that handles reordering.  You'll also need a method in your model that takes care of the database part of it.  Do you have those methods in place?

Comment: I have controller methods but there are no any properties.I can't understand what property should write in controller and model method.I will totally understand if I get a total sample example or total guidelines .Besides I have a column in database name data which will contain the the id of lists after reordering the list.But can't do that..